# Allow Script to run only on one Server IP

Tags: php

Is it possible to allow to run the script only on one Server IP with PHP?
Like an License for one User / Domain.

Can i use this line of Code to get the Server IP and block all other?:

```
$_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'];
```

If someone copy the script to an other servers ip its redirect to an other Page.
Just an Testing Script.

Thanks

Comment: It's certainly possible, but if someone has the code then there's absolutely nothing to stop them just removing that line.

Comment: Are you concerned that someone will get your PHP code and run it somewhere else or that someone will hotlink your content, or something else? If they have your code, they can remove the check as easily as you put it in. Easier, in fact.

Comment: I can encrypt it. But as i say, its just for testing not for selling my Script. Any examples how i can make it?

Comment: I second Iainn, if you give them the code there would be nothing stopping anyone from removing that line. Plus, restricting code to a specific IP would be delicate, as it would prevent your client to run on a specific machine, then move that to another server with different addresses (a common scenario in today's cloud era).

Comment: What i would do is to create a centralized service of validation, that would provide a require resource for your script to run. I mean that t this validation should be done ina place that you control, or as all comments have said, users will easily brake it.

Comment: Maybe obfuscating code might help. There's some third party tools that allows you to do this. But nothing is fail safe!

Comment: ( centralized service of validation, ) - Even then, someone might be able to cache that resource locally then strip out the license check.  Also, unless your license server has 100.00% uptime you're going to have very angry users when you break their servers because your server is offline.